# How to overwrite an entire table with the result of a SELECT query? (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-insert, overwrite

With the following query I create a table that is the result of the left join of two existing tables:

```
CREATE TABLE meal_reservations
SELECT 
    meal.id, 
    meal.max_reservations, 
    SUM(IFNULL(reservation.number_of_guests, 0)) AS reservations
FROM meal
LEFT OUTER JOIN reservation 
ON meal.id = reservation.meal_id
GROUP BY meal.id;
```

I would like to be able to update its values with the same `SELECT` query whenever I need to.

I tried `REPLACE INTO` but this just appended the new result on the existing rows.

Comment: What do *you* mean by "update its values with the same `SELECT` query?  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Would adding a `DROP TABLE meal_reservations` or `TRUNCATE TABLE meal_reservations` as line one do the deed

Comment: If you don't wish to drop or truncate the table then an INSERT..ON DUPLICATE KEY may be appropriate.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, P.Salmon - truncating the table is a perfectly fine solution, thanks!

Comment: @Strawberry obviously in this question MCRE was not necessary...

Comment: Obviously, I disagree. Questions and answers exist to benefit the entire SO community. Poor questions, tend to attract poor answers, which benefit no one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about truncating the table and then re-filling it with an `insert ... select ...` statement? That's the simplest approach I can think of. Otherwise, you would need to define exactly how you want to manage the delta, which can be tedious.

```
-- empty the table
truncate table meal_reservations;

-- fill it again
insert into meal_reservations
SELECT 
    meal.id, 
    meal.max_reservations, 
    SUM(IFNULL(reservation.number_of_guests, 0)) AS reservations
FROM meal
LEFT OUTER JOIN reservation 
ON meal.id = reservation.meal_id
GROUP BY meal.id;
```